# How to make GCC tell me the output file name it used?

Tags: c, gcc

I am invoking GCC with some arbitrary arguments that are given to me by another script.

Is there any argument I can add that will **tell** me the exact name of the output file **without** changing it and **without** requiring me to parse the arguments myself?

Comment: I don't think that's achievable without *any* parsing. However, it might (or might not) be more straightforward if you tried to add the `-v` option. GCC is then supposed to produce an long output documenting every step it undertakes with all the options, including those inferred. On the other hand you will then have to separate the wheat from the chaff to have only useful diagnostics remain.

Comment: No there isn't, because an arbitary invocation of gcc, even if successful,
may generate 0, 1 or many output files. Can you say that the gcc invocations you have to deal with are ones that *should create an executable* (program or shared library)? Anyhow, as @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, says, you must either parse the arguments or else request verbose output from `gcc` and parse that.
The former will be easier unless the arguments as you receive them can
contain unexpanded environment variables.

Comment: Modifying the other script is possibly the easier option.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: Where exactly does `-v` list the output file name? The only instances where I see it listed at all occur in the `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS` variable, which is what GCC *received* from me, which is equivalent to parsing the arguments... I don't see anything else.

Comment: @Mehrdad, don't have a computer with GCC at hand to check, but last time I launched it with `-v` option, it listed all the internally executed commands such as `cc1` and `ld`, and they all contained the explicit `-o` option. I don't know, though, how diverse the output is in different versions.

Comment: With `gcc -v`, the output filename will be mentioned in the `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS` and again - if linkage is done - in the very long linkage commandline, e.g. ` /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 ... -o filename ... ` But in both cases *only if* `-o filename` *was present in the invocation arguments*, which need not be the case. The only way you can know that exactly one output file is expected, and that it will be mentioned in the verbose output, is by finding `-o filename` in the
invocation arguments. So you might as well do that in first place.